# Is it possible to port forwarding to my web server if my router is using a private ip?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have HTTP server on my LAN and I want devices on the internet to be able to connect to my server.I set up my router to forward all the traffic that is coming to port 8080 to the http server.However ,when I tried to connect to the server from a device on the internet ,it did not work.I check the router's ip it was something like 10.x.x.x a private IP.Is this the cause of the problem?? Isn’t there anyway to get around this??

Comment: if your ISP is giving you a private WAN address, then no, there is nothing you can do, except seek help from directly them (which they may or may6 not be willing to provide).

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "a private ip".  Strictly speaking if your being assigned 10.x.x.x by your ISP you can't view websites.

Comment: If your external IP address is 10.x.x.x and you are being sold an Internet service, demand your money back and move to a real ISP as you are not getting what you are paying for.  A competent ISP should NEVER provide service on the 10.x.x.x network.  If they really need to use NAT they should use Carrier Grade NAT in the 100.64.0.0/10

Comment: @Ramhound, it sounds like Carrier-grade NAT to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT

Comment: I am aware, my point, was that his public up address can't be what he thinks it is

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an [private ip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces) outside your private network.
To connect to your webserver from a device outside your network you need to find your public ip. This can be found using online tools like [this one](http://whatismyip.org/). Then use that ip in combination with the port to connect.

```
http://8.8.8.8:8080
```

Please note that your public ip address might change unless your isp has set up a static address.

Answer (score 0):

Your router will have (at least) 2 IP addresses - the 10.x.x.x address is probably the LAN Interface.   Additionally you will have an IP address on the WAN interface (or being accessed across it in the case of PPP or similar) - this external IP address is the one you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

If your router's WAN address is 10.x.x.x, then you most likely have a DSL/Cable modem which is acting as a gateway.  You will need to be able to log into the modem and make changes to fix this.  The simplest fix would be to just forward port 8080 to the 10.x.x.x IP address on the WAN interface of your router.  The more complicated (but better) way would be to switch the modem from "gateway" mode to "pass-through" mode, so that the external Internet IP address would be configured on your router's WAN port, instead of on the modem's WAN port.  You would need to make sure to disable DHCP on the modem, set it to pass-through mode, and then reconfigure your router's WAN interface with the external Internet IP address you were assigned.  Then, you would only need to forward ports on your router and you wouldn't ever need to log into your modem again.